# String to int with BufferedReader

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, text-parsing

I have this code but when I try to run it I got this error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"`
Every line is contains a number a name an email and a date so the first character in every line is the number. The `tomb[0]` is just a number

```
List<Szemely> lista = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.szemelyekcsv))) {
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tomb;
                tomb = line.split(";");

               int sor = Integer.parseInt(tomb [0]);
                DateTimeFormatter sima = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
                LocalDate szul = LocalDate.parse(tomb[3], sima);


                lista.add(new Szemely(sor, tomb[1], tomb[2], szul));

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Nem tudom megnyitni a 'be.txt' fájlt.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Hiba a 'be.txt' fájl olvasása közben.");
        }
```

when the program reach this line

```
int sor = Integer.parseInt(tomb [0]);
```

automaticly jump back to

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.szemelyekcsv)))
```

and error...
thanks all help.

Comment: what is tomb[0] .. .try to print it first ...

Comment: oh sorry. every line is contains a number a name an email and a date. so the first character in every line is the number.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] this is strange that the exception give the String `"1"` since this should be parsable. For the example, you probably don't need a `File`, one `String` should be enough, just try if this is reproducible before posting it

Comment: @SantiBailors it seems that they are separated by ";" and he split them into tomb array.

Comment: @pooyan You're right, I just figured that out so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @AxelH is it possible that problem caused by saved format of file? i mean it is possible that in the format that he saved the files we have character "1" that is not known as "1" for compiler? i hope you understand my mean.

Comment: @pooyan Yes, I understand and this is a good suggestion, this could be a special character representing a `1`, this is why I said to test if the String reproduce the problem ;) just in case. Of course, it is easy to print the bytes representation to see if it is [1](https://unicode-table.com/fr/#0031) or not

Comment: Trying printing `tomb[0].length()`.  I suspect there is a non-printing character in the string.  For instance, it might be `"\ufeff1"`.

Comment: If there are invisible characters you could fix the problem like this: `Integer.parseInt(tomb[0].replaceAll("[^0-9]+", ""));`

Comment: Thank you maraca. this is solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [pooyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2398444/pooyan), [AxelH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4391450/axelh) and [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) pointed out the problem was indeed one or more invisible characters (e.g. control characters).

One way to solve this is cut away everything that's not a digit using regular expressions:

```
int sor = Integer.parseInt(tomb[0].replaceAll("[^0-9]+", ""));
```

`[^...]` = not those characters

`[0-9]` = digits

`+` = one or more times

Comment: Alternatively just doing a trim() on the input string may be enough and in a way is safer as you will still detect bad inputs.